# Javascript: Display contents of one div, make others invisible

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a function that takes in an id of a div, checks that id against a list of other ids, displays the div relevant to the passed-in id, and causes all other divs for the ids in the list to not be displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_page(id) {
//list of ids that I want to check against
   var pages = ['home', 'about', 'listen', 'more']; 
    for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
        var e = document.getElementById(pages[i]);
        if (pages[i] == id){
            e.style.display = 'block';
            alert(e);
        } 
        else{
             e.style.display = 'none';  
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my function calls are structured like this:

```
<li class="active" class="test"><a href="#" onclick="display_page('home');">Home</a></li>
```

Not sure why this isn't working -- as a note, my ids are unique so I don't think that's the issue. The alerts are not showing up though upon clicking the relevant links (like the one posted above). Thanks for the help!

Comment: where are the id(s) in your HTML code

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Instead of display none/block, consider adding and removing a class.

Comment: is there a deep hatred or some other issue with jQuery , this can be done in one line of code .  I'm not going to put it in answer because you did not use jQuery tag

Comment: @ScottSelby—perhaps the OP would rather write 5 lines of code and have it run much faster, and not be dependent on 4,000 lines or so of other code. Greater or fewer lines of code is not, by itself, a reason to adopt any particular solution.

Comment: I understand that -- that's why I didn't put a jquery answer here.  but there were times I worte similar comment and OP was interested in learning the alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *querySelectorAll* to help here:

```
function display_page(id) {

    var pages = document.querySelectorAll('#home, #about, #listen, #more');

    for (var i=0, iLen=pages.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      pages[i].style.display = pages[i].id == id? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

I wonder when an iterator will be added to the NodeList interface so we can do:

```
var id = 'home';
document.querySelectorAll('#home, #about, #listen, #more').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = el.id == id? '' : 'none';
});
```

Note that toggling between 'none' and '' (empty string) is preferred so that the element adopts its default or inherited style and you don't have to hard–code what that might be.

Oh, without qSA:

```
function display_page(id) {
    var ids = ['home', 'about', 'listen', 'more'];

    for (var i=0, iLen=ids.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      page = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
      page.style.display = page.id == id? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

This one depends on ES5 *forEach*:

```
function display_page(showId) {
    ['home', 'about', 'listen', 'more'].forEach(function(id) {
        var page = document.getElementById(id);
        page.style.display = page.id == showId? '' : 'none';
    });
}
```

Comment: This really helped see different approaches to solve what I was confused about -- figured it out now. Thanks!